# Map frame in the map composer doesn't show the project layers when the size of the map is too large. Small size maps work fine

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer

I drew a map in QGIS print composer, but it does not render my layer from the QGIS project. When I reduce the size of my map it works. Here are two pictures to illustrate my issue. [image]

[image]

Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: Do you have scale-based visibility set for this layer?